# disable access to tomcat by browser from remote location

Tags: java, apache, security, tomcat

i have install mod_jk i want to disable access to tomcat directly using localhost:8080/webApp
.it should be only accessible through apache server using mod_jk module and user is also not able to see `webApp` in url.

Answer (score 1):

You can comment out in server.xml file the Connector of type http.

This will make tomcat only listen on the ajp connector.

Regards

Philippe

Comment: thanks can you plz tell me also how to disable so webApp is also not visible in path

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138865/how-to-mount-context-referenced-tomcat-application-with-mod-jk